# scanf function Absorption of 01

Tags: c

Hello everyone I wanted to know if I wanted to pick up the number 01 without using the strings it is possible because when i register it in scanf it refers to those i registered only one
I thought I might pick up 1 in char and 0 in char but I do not want to get off line reception I want it to be in the same line
Is there a possibility to do this without strings
Thanks for the helpers for example `int x=0;  scanf("%d ",&x);`
And I want him to be inside X 01

Comment: You ask about a C function, so why the C# language tag? Please don't spam with tags just because you *think* they are the same. Please take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Probably mistakenly how I delete it

Comment: Your question doesn't really have an answer.  Fundamentally, you need to understand that strings store characters; integer types store values.  Because there is no difference between the numeric value of `1` and the numeric value of `01`, any attempt to distinguish the two using `scanf()` with a `%d` conversion specifier will be doomed to fail.  If you want to pick up the exact user input, you should use strings.  Two questions for you:  why don't you want to use strings?  and do you know the input will always be exactly two characters? It's hard to see exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: It is a task and a record that needs two characters and a zero should come first for example 02
And no string that we have not learned yet I thought I might store the 0 in char and the 1 in char but it goes down a row and I do not want it to happen

Comment: Please edit your question to include the input, and exactly what you're trying to do with it.  Also, it would be easier to understand you if you would please use punctuation.

Comment: Yes, but I want to take in two digits in the same line

Comment: It goes down a line

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer

```
printf("%02d",x);
```

this is the answer Someone knows why this is happening